# Why is my Properties empty even though I have WinUI 3 Tools installed in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2022, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition, version 17.4.1. I'm working on an app that uses WinUI 3 SDK and I noticed that my properties is empty. I initially though this was due to WinUI 3 being new (compared to WPF or UWP) however I saw few videos online that Properties had values. What am I missing here?

[image: Properties missing]

Comment: I've been working with WinUI 3 for a while but I've never noticed any values in the properties. You might have seen the "Live Property Explorer" where you can see properties for controls.

Comment: Only WPF and UWP XAML editors have properties here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm closing this question.